# How to read CSV files with header definition in a separate file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read large csv files that has a separate file containing the headers for the columns, example below

Sample CSV *part_000.csv* (pipe delimited):

```
000c7c09-66d7-47d6-9415-87e5010fe282|2019-04-08|EMAIL|active|43
030c2309-44d7-4676-7815-83e5010f3256|2019-03-18|EMAIL|lapsed|32
```

Sample header file *_HEADER*:

```
cid|character varying(36)
startdate|date
channel|character varying(20)
status|character varying(6)
age|integer
```

How can I read the CSV files and use the header file to assign the schema?

Comment: Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317002/spark-programmatically-creating-dataframe-schema-in-scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a schema based on the HEADER file, and then read your data using the schema:

```
 def defineType(str: String): DataType = {
    str match {
      case "date" => DateType
      case "integer" => IntegerType
      case x if x.startsWith("character") => StringType
      //  ... other types and logic
    }
  }

  def createSchema(pathToSchema: String): StructType = {
    val schemaDF = spark.read.option("sep", "|").csv(pathToSchema)
    val fields: Array[StructField] = schemaDF.collect().map(row => StructField(row.getString(0), defineType(row.getString(1))))
    StructType(fields)
  }

  val schema = createSchema("./data/csv_data/HEADER.csv")

  val df = spark.read.option("sep", "|").schema(schema).csv("./data/csv_data/part_000.csv")

  df.show(false)
  df.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+------+---+
|cid                                 |startdate |channel|status|age|
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+------+---+
|000c7c09-66d7-47d6-9415-87e5010fe282|2019-04-08|EMAIL  |active|43 |
|030c2309-44d7-4676-7815-83e5010f3256|2019-03-18|EMAIL  |lapsed|32 |
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+------+---+

root
 |-- cid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- startdate: date (nullable = true)
 |-- channel: string (nullable = true)
 |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
```